# Autofac using Constructor

Tags: entity-framework, repository, autofac, unit-of-work

I use unit of work pattern with entityFramework code first. Now I want to use *Autofac* to register UnitOfWork, Repositories and My dbContext.

This Is my `UnitOfWork` code:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;

    public UnitOfWork(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;

        Contact = new ContractRepository(context);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
        GC.SuppressFinalize(_context);
    }

    public IContactRepository Contact { get; private set; }

    public int Complete()
    {
        return _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

and this is my repository:

```
public class Repository<Entity> : IRepository<Entity> where Entity : class
{
    protected readonly DbContext _noteBookContext;
    public Repository(DbContext noteBookContext)
    {
        _noteBookContext = noteBookContext;
    }
    public void Add(Entity entity)
    {
        _noteBookContext.Set<Entity>().Add(entity);
    }
}
```

and this is one of my repositories:

```
public  class ContractRepository: Repository<Contact>,IContactRepository 
{
    public ContractRepository(DbContext noteBookContext) : base(noteBookContext)
    {

    }

    public DbContext NotebookContext
    {
        get
        {
            return _noteBookContext;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my db context class:

```
public class NoteBookContext:DbContext
{
    public NoteBookContext(string connectionstring):base(connectionstring)
    {

    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ContactConfig());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PhoneConfig());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PhoneTypeConfig());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new GroupConfig());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Phone> Phones { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }

    public DbSet<PhoneType> PhoneTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to register UnitOfWork with constructor (a constructor like this: )

```
var uow = new UnitOfWork(new NotebookdbContext("connectionstring"));
```

Note that NoteBookContext is my entity framework model.

I write registration but I got Error:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<NoteBookContext>()
       .As<DbContext>();
builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>()
       .UsingConstructor(typeof(DbContext))
       .As<IUnitOfWork>();

builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<>))
       .As(typeof(IRepository<>))
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

Container container = builder.Build();
```

This is my error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException' occurred in Autofac.dll
>   Additional information: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'DataLayer.NoteBookContext' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
>
> Cannot resolve parameter 'System.String connectionstring' of
>   constructor 'Void .ctor(System.String)'.

Edit 2 :

after help from Cyril Durand's answer I write following registering config:

```
 var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<ConnectionStringProvider>().As<IConnectionStringProvider>();
        builder.RegisterType<NoteBookContext>().As<DbContext>().WithParameter((pi, c) => pi.Name == "connectionstring",
                                                                              (pi, c) => c.Resolve<IConnectionStringProvider>().ConnectionString);
        builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().WithParameter(ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<DbContext>("connectionstring"));
        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

and In my code :

```
using (var scope = DependencyInjection.Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var ConnectionString = scope.Resolve<IConnectionStringProvider>();
            ConnectionString.ConnectionString = "Context";

            var uw = scope.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>();
            var a =uw.Contact.GetAll();

        }
```

but I got Error again:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException' occurred in Autofac.dll
>
> Additional information: An exception was thrown while invoking the
>   constructor 'Void .ctor(System.String)' on type 'NoteBookContext'.

can everyone help me?

Comment: Could you edit your post and include the error message ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand : I include error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message :

> An unhandled exception of type `Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException` occurred in *Autofac.dll* 
>   Additional information: None of the constructors found with `Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder` on type `DataLayer.NoteBookContext` can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
>
> Cannot resolve parameter `System.String connectionstring` of constructor `Void .ctor(System.String)`.

tells you that *Autofac* can't create a `NoteBookContext` because it can't resolve a parameter named `connectionstring` of type `String`.

Your `NoteBookContext` implementation needs a connectionstring, *Autofac* can't know it without you telling it. When you register the `NoteBookContext` you will have to specify the connectionstring :

```
builder.RegisterType<NoteBookContext>()
       .As<DbContext>()
       .WithParameter("connectionstring", "XXX");
```

Another solution with dynamic resolution and a `IConnectionStringProvider` interface :

```
public interface IConnectionStringProvider
{
    public String ConnectionString { get; }
}
```

and registration :

```
builder.RegisterType<ConnectionStringProvider>()
       .As<IConnectionStringProvider>()
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope(); 
builder.RegisterType<NoteBookContext>()
       .As<DbContext>()
       .WithParameter((pi, c) => pi.Name == "connectionstring", 
                      (pi, c) => c.Resolve<IConnectionStringProvider>().ConnectionString)
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Comment: how can I add a parameter and set value in resolve time?

Comment: many thanks for your answers. actually I want end programmer at resolve time pass parameter value. is it possible?

Comment: sorry I got error again , with your solution. how can I solve and what am I wrong?

Comment: @minamorsali `IConnectionStringProvider` is registered as `InstancePerDependency`. Each time you resolve it, you will have a new instance. So the instance you modify is different from the instance resolved by `DbContext`. In order to share the instance, you will have to declare it with `InstancePerLifetimeScope`

Comment: Great answer helped me in my situation where I have an Autofac module class to register my classes etc.  I had issues with EfCore so I first needed to create the DbContextOptions object then with the .WithParameter function to pass in the options parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing error. But You don't need to use `UsingConstructor`.

```
//Make DbContext per request, if your app is web app (which has http request).
builder.RegisterType<NoteBookContext>()
       .As<DbContext>().WithParameter("connectionstring","ConnectionStringValue").InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<>))
       .As(typeof(IRepository<>))
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

Container = builder.Build();
```

Comment: I test your code instead of mine , this cause following error: An unhandled exception of type 'Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException' occurred in Autofac.dll , Additional information: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'BussinessLayer.Repositories.UnitOfWork' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:

Comment: Only one constructor

Comment: Can you share your db context constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you want to pass the connection string to your context? Create an interface for your unitofwork and do something like this:

```
public class NoteBookContext:DbContext
{
    //Change connectionstring below with the name of your connection string in web.config
    public NoteBookContext():base("name=connectionstring")
    {

    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ContactConfig());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PhoneConfig());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PhoneTypeConfig());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new GroupConfig());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Phone> Phones { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }

    public DbSet<PhoneType> PhoneTypes { get; set; }
}
```

And register like this:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<NoteBookContext>()
       .As<DbContext>()
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>()
       .As<IUnitOfWork>()
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<>))
       .As(typeof(IRepository<>))
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

Container container = builder.Build();
```